# How to show scraped updated data on a table on website page?

Tags: python, html

I typed this code to scrape an updated data (numbers). I have no idea how to show them on a table on a website. I know I should use (Django or flask) but I don't know how to use them both :). I just wanna show these updated numbers on a table. I am using HTML and python on Vs Code. here is my scraping code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

getpage= requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/austria/')
getpage_soup= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')
Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases= getpage_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'maincounter-number'})
for para in Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases:
    print (para.text)
```

and here is the updated (day by day ) data result:

```
589,299     
9,843
550,470
```

thanks :)

Comment: you do this by without django and flask check this documentation for more information  https://zetcode.com/python/jinja/

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna show the data in a table you can use pandas.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
getpage= requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/austria/')
getpage_soup= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')
Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases= getpage_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'maincounter-number'})
result = [(para.text).strip().split(',') for para in Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases] # creating (list of list)
df = pd.DataFrame(result) # loading result into dataframe
print(df)
```

The above code will print table(You can change the dataframe column names if required) -

```
    0   1
0   589 299
1   9   843
2   550 470
```

Now, there are too many options to save this dataframe. You can save the table in excel file / csv_file or even as an HTML table.

```
df.to_excel('ouput.xlsx', index=False)
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
df.to_html('out.html')
```

HTML file will look like this -

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>589</td>
      <td>299</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>843</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>550</td>
      <td>470</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```